# Magento2: How to get product collection by full text search?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, fulltext

How to get product collection by full text search?

```
        $query = $this->queryFactory->get()->getQueryText();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$query.'%'));
        $collection->setPageSize(10); // fetching only 10 products
```

Any one help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below url :

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1121

I hope its work for you.